# Where to find a study on women and selfies?

Tags: social-psychology, abnormal-psychology, experimental-psychology, social-desirability, social-neuroscience

I have recently read the following Yahoo article: [Guys, this is why you should never post too many selfies on social media](https://in.lifestyle.yahoo.com/guys-why-never-post-too-many-selfies-social-053412852.html).

This article describes a study that correlates selfies taken by men and their psychology.

So my question is where to find a similar study about women?

Answer (score 7):

The Yahoo Lifestyle website gives a popular description of the following study:

[**Fox & Rooney**. The Dark Triad and trait self-objectification as predictors of men’s use and self-presentation behaviors on social networking sites. *Personality and Individual Differences* **76** (2015) 161–165](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0191886914007259)

The study basically concludes that in a population of males (and I quote from the abstract):

> Self-objectification and narcissism predicted time spent on SNSs.
>   Narcissism and psychopathy predicted the number of selfies posted, whereas narcissism and
>   self-objectification predicted editing photographs of oneself posted on SNSs.

With regard to females, the authors justify their choice of a male population on p.162 at the end of the Introduction, and I quote:

> Although some research on SNSs and other interactive media has shown a relationship between use and self-objectification among females (e.g., Fox, Bailenson, & Tricase, 2013; Fox, Ralston, Cooper, & Jones, in press; De Vries & Peter, 2013; Meier & Gray, 2013; Vandenbosch & Eggermont, 2012), at this time little is known about men. Given previous findings with females, we anticipate that trait self-objectification will be associated with greater social networking site use [...], more frequently posting selfies [...], and more frequent photo editing [...] by men.

In other words, **in females the relation between self-objectification and use of interactive media was already known. The authors have therefore addressed the issue in a population of men.**

Sifting through the studies cited in the Fox & Rooney article, and taking into account that your question emphasizes your interest in selfies, the De Vries and Peter study cited in the quote above is probably the reference you are after:

[**De Vries and Peter**. Women on display: The effect of portraying the self online on
women’s self-objectification. *Computers in Human Behavior* **29** (2013) 1483–1489](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257253074_Women_on_display_The_effect_of_portraying_the_self_online_on_women%27s_self-objectification)